# Learning roadmap request: compiling a "Mathematics Stack Exchange Undergraduate Bibliography"

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, big-list, book-recommendation

`[Book recommendation]` questions are quite popular on this website, which is, at least for me, one of the best places to get useful and insightful suggestions because it gathers a great number of experts in different areas of mathematics.

In my opinion, it would be very beneficial for the organization of the site (and for the many undergraduate students searching for guidance when facing a new course or looking for a good learning roadmap -- like myself) to make one thread that collects a big *"Mathematics Stack Exchange Undergraduate Mathematics Bibliography"* divided by categories just like the nice one proposed [here](https://www.ocf.berkeley.edu/~abhishek/chicmath.htm), but surely more comprehensive (given the much larger number of contributors).

This thread should collect sparse *material already available* on the website but hard to find among the numerous questions and also *new inputs*. Ideally each entry should be briefly commented with matter-of-fact remarks.

Comment: Is it a good idea to collect all recommendations in a single answer?  This short circuits some of the most useful stack exchange functionality, such as upvoting good answers.

Comment: @littleO I know, but having 100 answers would make the list much less organized. What do you propose to do?

Comment: @littleO For example, it is always possible to add a little remark on an entry which is, for some reasons, considered by common agreement "no good" pointing out the exact *objective* reasons.

Comment: Personally I suspect that it's more useful to have separate threads for separate subjects. We can find the relevant threads easily by googling. Perhaps we should have one master thread that collects links to threads for different subjects.  However it's quite possible that many people will find this list useful and there's no harm in making it.

Comment: I think books mentioned on [tag:book-recommendation], should have the question linked.

Comment: Best suited for Meta, IMHO.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I don't think so, because, even though it is a little bit broader than the average book recommendation question, it is still a question on finding a suitable learning roadmap and bibliography.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

*Please, add your contributions to this answer (which I made community wiki). In case you wish to add some personal comments about your entries, add a tag like `[Your_Username]`.*

---

### Foundations

[Daniel J. Velleman, H*ow
    to Prove It: A Structured Approach*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521675995)

### Problem solving

1. [G. Polya, *How to Solve It: A New Aspect of Mathematical Method*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/069116407X)

### Recreational

### Algebra

- [Roger Godement](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0006E00F0)  , *Algebra*     (Translation of *Cours d' Algebre*)
- Lang - Algebra
- Jacobson - Basic Algebra I, Basic Algebra II
- Rotman - Introduction to the Theory of Groups
- Dummit and Foote - Algebra
- Hungerford - Abstract Algebra
- Serre - Linear Representations of Finite Groups
- Fulton, Harris - Representation Theory - A First Course
- Humphreys - Introduction to Lie Algebras and Representation Theory
- Atiyah, MacDonald - Introduction to Commutative Algebra
- Eisenbud - Commutative Algebra: with a View Toward Algebraic Geometry
- Weibel - An Introduction to Homological Algebra

### Linear algebra

- [Sheldon Axler, *Linear Algebra Done Right*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3319110799)

- Sergei Treil, *Linear Algebra Done Wrong*

- Roman - Advanced Linear Algebra

### Geometry

- Mumford - The Red Book of Varieties and Schemes

### Point-set topology

### Differential geometry

- John Lee, *Introduction to Smooth Manifolds
  *

### Number theory

- Andre Weil, *Basic Number Theory*

- Ireland and Rosen - A Classical Introduction to Moder Number Theory
- Edmund Landau - Introduction to Number Theory
- Burton - Elementary Number Theory

### Combinatorics and discrete mathematics

- [Graham, Knuth, Patashnik, *Concrete Mathematics*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0201558025)

### Probability and Statistics

### Real analysis

- Gerald B. Folland, *Real Analysis: Modern Techniques and Their Applications*

- Shilov and  Gurevich: Integral, Measure and Derivative.

### Multivariable calculus

- [Spivak, *Calculus On Manifolds*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0805390219)

### Complex analysis

- [Tristan Needham, *Visual Complex Analysis*.](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198534469)
- Remmert - Introduction to the Theory of Functions.
- Remmert - Classical Topics in Function Theory

### Differential equations

### Functional analysis

- Walter Rudin, *Functional Analysis*
- Erwin Kreyszig, *Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications*
- Reinhold Meise & Dietmar Vogt: *[Introduction to Functional Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0198514859)*

### Mathematical and theoretical physics

- Arnold - Mathematical Methods of Classical Mechanics

Comment: for undergraduate real analysis. Folland ?

Comment: Some schools in China, Japan, Germany, Russia and UK use Folland, adult Rudin or Royden in undergrad as far as I know.

Comment: @AranKomatsuzaki In addition, such topics are covered in your 2nd and 3rd year of university in my country. So that book is totally fine (and, by the way, I like it).